Constructing a sparse matrix with some constraints
I want to construct a sparse matrix  $A \in \mathcal{R}^{K\times L}  $ with some rules.
The rules are as follows:

Each row must have $T_r$ nonzero elements
The maximum number of nonzero elements in each column is $T_c$

Assume that the nonzero element is 1.
And there are some constraints:

$K \cdot T_r \leq L  \cdot T_c $
$\frac{L}{T_r}$ is integer.
$T_c \leq 0.2 \cdot K$

Example parameters : $K=500,\  L=200 ,\ T_r=25,\ T_c=100$
Is there a general method to construct matrix $A$?
Thank you in advance for your response.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but surely placing the $1$s equally spaced on each row, forming diagonals, e.g.$$\pmatrix{1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0}$$would be the best way to go? You are guaranteed to have $T_r$ ones in each row, and the maximum number of ones in each column would be minimal (in that, any other configuration would have at least as many ones in at least one column).

Thanks for your answer! I think the diagonal pattern may be best option. If the spacing of nonzero elements in each row is $\frac{L}{T_r}$, that satisifies the first rule and guarantees the minimum number of elements in each column.
